# How can select and load form?

Tags: django

I want to select option 1 and load a form with inputs

HTML:

```
 <select id="orden" class="form-control" name="orden">
                <option disabled selected>Selecciona una opci&oacute;n</option>
                <option value="1">{{ results.1.op_ser_codigo }}{{ results.1.op_num_codigo }} / ({{ results.1.data_ini }} - {{ results.1.data_fim }})</option>
                <option value="2">{{ results.2.op_ser_codigo }}{{ results.2.op_num_codigo }} / ({{ results.2.data_ini }} - {{ results.2.data_fim }})</option>
                <option value="3">{{ results.3.op_ser_codigo }}{{ results.3.op_num_codigo }} / ({{ results.3.data_ini }} - {{ results.3.data_fim }})</option>
                 <option value="4">{{ results.4.op_ser_codigo }}{{ results.4.op_num_codigo }} / ({{ results.4.data_ini }} - {{ results.4.data_fim }})</option>
                 <option value="5">{{ results.5.op_ser_codigo }}{{ results.5.op_num_codigo }} / ({{ results.5.data_ini }} - {{ results.5.data_fim }})</option>
                 <option value="6">{{ results.6.op_ser_codigo }}{{ results.6.op_num_codigo }} / ({{ results.6.data_ini }} - {{ results.6.data_fim }})</option>
             </select>
```

I want to fill this: (If on select option i select 1 on this inputs fill value 1)

```
 <b><p class="black">OP: </b>{{ results.1.op_ser_codigo }}{{results.1.op_num_codigo}} </p>
            <b><p class="black">Fecha Inicio: </b>{{ results.1.data_ini }} </p>
            <b><p class="black">Fecha Final: </b> {{ results.1.data_fim }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it on client side (with jq, javascript) or on the server side. I definitely advice to handle it on the server side - as business logic should be there. Although in this case - as I understand - the trigger will come after the form is loaded and once the select options is selected.

I would go with an ajax solution.

1. place an onchange event to the select:
   eg:

   onchange="ChooseOption(this.value)"
2. add javascript to handle ajax request(I use jquery):

   function ChooseOption(option_id){
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/applicatioin/option_selection/",
   data: {
   'option_id' : option_id,
   'csrfmiddlewaretoken' :
   $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
   },
   success: chooseoptionDetailSuccess,
   dataType: 'html'
   });
   }

In the success you call chooseoptionDetailSuccess function. Which should pass the data to the relevant html field - with innerHtml.
Note: you may also use GET request type.

3. In you django view you have to render a html template which holds the html part (with the variables) which will be changed.

Sorry for the format. Seems like the code sample is not working.